# Bind and retrieve managed bean to Composite Control

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have an XHTML structure as follows,

```
<h:dataTable value="#{mainBean.customerlist}" var="c">
  <h:column>
   <h:panelGrid rendered="#{c.renderclient}">
     *html design for client*
   </h:panelGrid>
   <h:panelGrid rendered="#{c.renderadmin}">
     *html design for admin*
   </h:panelGrid>
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

`mainBean.customerlist` contains list of managed beans. What I need is to replace these h:panelGrid with composite controls. But no idea how to pass managed beans from `mainBean.customerlist` to Composite Controls. Or is any other better way to achieve the same?